# Why do I keep getting an error when running vagrant up on the Big Sur MacOS

Tags: laravel, debugging, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I've been stuck on this for a few days now and have ran out of options on what to do next.

I've recently purchased a new macbook pro.  I backed up my old macbook pro on my external hard drive and imported everything to my new macbook pro.  This means that all of my old macbook pro's contents/configs are now on my new macbook pro.

The OS on my old macbook pro is Catalina while the OS on my new macbook pro is Big Sur.

Whenever I try to run `vagrant up` in my `/Homestead` directory - I get this error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

The most common solution I see is that I'd need navigate to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Allow Oracle permission**.  However, I don't even see that as an option appearing when navigated to this.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Vagrant and Virtual Box (followed [Laravel Homestead docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead#first-steps)), but it didn't work.

I have no idea what else to do.  This whole Virtual Box thing was working fine on my old macbook pro.  On my new macbook pro, it's giving me a ton of problems.

Anyone have any suggestions on what I should do?  I've exhausted almost everything I can find on the web, hoping I can come across an answer that may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of vagrant up, try to execute the command :

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

It is going to reboot your VM. Maybe something in the setup needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Any updates to this question? @sp92 Please feel free to share with us the steps you made in order to overcome this error message.